Unable to SSH using Public IP Address During Deployment in CI/CD Pipeline
I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for my project, and during the deployment stage, I need to SSH into my server using a public IP address. However, I'm encountering an issue where the SSH connection times out when using the public IP
Here's my setup:

Public IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Local IP: 192.168.31.234
SSH port: 22 (both internally and externally)

What I've tried:
Local network access: SSH works perfectly with the local IP (192.168.31.234) using the command:

ssh sourov@192.168.31.234

Port forwarding setup on my router:

External port: 22
Internal IP address: 192.168.31.234
Internal port: 22

Firewall settings: UFW is configured to allow SSH (port 22) on both IPv4 and IPv6:
bash
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
ssh sourov@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Results in the error:
ssh: connect to host 45.120.115.234 port 22: No route to host

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      
      - name: Run Django migrations
        run: python manage.py migrate
        working-directory : ./dining_manager
      
      - name : Run Django test
        run : python manage.py test
        working-directory : ./dining_manager

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    
    steps:
      - name: Check out the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Test SSH Connectivity
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sourov@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo 'SSH connection successful'"

      
      - name: Copy files to the server
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.1
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          target: /var/www/dajngo_graphql
          source: ./ 
          port: 22                
          timeout: "30s"                           

      - name: Execute deploy commands over SSH
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd /var/www/dajngo_graphql
            source myenvenv/bin/activate
            cd /var/www/django_graphql/dining_manager
            python manage.py migrate
            python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
            sudo systemctl restart your-gunicorn-service
        ```

